# Append all possibilities from sequences with numbers

Tags: python, append, sequence

I have a question that is consuming my brain. Let us suppose that the variable I stores a sequence, and the variable II another one, and the variable III another one too. The variable one will represent the number 1, the next 2 and the next 3; and then I have another key variable with random characters of these 3 sequences. Giving that fact, I can easily translate the characters of this key variable in the correspondent numbers. In the example, `x = 'afh'`, than, it is the same to say that `x = '123'`, because A OR B OR C = 1, and so on.

Now comes the complicated part:

When the key variable x is translated into numbers, each character individually, I can also return characters randomly from the result. For example: `x = '123'`, then I can return a list like `['a','e','f']`, or `['b','d','i']`, especially if I use `random.choice()`. From this, what I couldn't figure out how to do yet is:

How can I append into a list ALL THE POSSIBLE VARIATIONS from the variables I, II, III. For example:

```
['adg','beh','cfi','aei','ceg',...]
```

I know how to print endlessly random combinations, but in this case, I get repetitions, and I don't want them. I want to append to a list exactly all the possible variations between I, II and III, because when they're translated into numbers, I can return any character from the correspondent sequence. Well, I hope my example is self-explainable. I thank you all very much for the attention!

```
I = 'abc' # 1
II = 'def' # 2
III = 'ghi' # 3
x = 'afh' # Random possibility: It could be an input.
L = []
LL = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] in I:
        L.append(1)
    if x[i] in II:
        L.append(2)
    if x[i] in III:
        L.append(3)

for i in range(len(L)): # Here lies the mistery...
    if L[i] == 1:
        LL.append(I) 
    if L[i] == 2:
        LL.append(II)
    if L[i] == 3:
        LL.append(III)

print L
print LL
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3]

['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Comment: More examples on "all possibilities"? I understand the translation from x to `[1,2,3]` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would rewrite your code. Lengthy if statements like yours are a big code smell. I put the sequences into a tuple and used a single loop. I also replaced the second loop with a list comprehension.

By the way, you could also simplify the indexing if you used zero based indexing like a sensible person.

```
I = 'abc' # 1
II = 'def' # 2
III = 'ghi' # 3
x = 'afh' # Random possibility: It could be an input.
L = []
LL = []

lists = I, II, III

for c in x:
    for i, seq in enumerate(lists):
        if c in seq:
            L.append(i+1)

LL = [lists[i-1] for i in L]

print L
print LL
```

Also, be sure to check out the `itertools` module, and in particular the `product` function. It's not clear exactly what you mean, but product gives you all combinations of an item from each of a list of sequences.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll check it out :). I was trying to do this without importing anything all the time, really really puzzling.

Comment: Very interesting!!! I'll take some time to fully understand your advanced way of rewriting my code, really good! Thank you! I'll check it for sure..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Antimony! The answer is exactly product() from itertools. The code with it is bloody far more simple:

```
from itertools import *

I = 'abc' # 1
II = 'def' # 2
III = 'ghi' # 3

IV = product(I,II,III)

for i in IV:
    print i
```

And the output is exactly what I wanted, every possible combination:

```
('a', 'd', 'g')
('a', 'd', 'h')
('a', 'd', 'i')
('a', 'e', 'g')
('a', 'e', 'h')
('a', 'e', 'i')
('a', 'f', 'g')
('a', 'f', 'h')
('a', 'f', 'i')
('b', 'd', 'g')
('b', 'd', 'h')
('b', 'd', 'i')
('b', 'e', 'g')
('b', 'e', 'h')
('b', 'e', 'i')
('b', 'f', 'g')
('b', 'f', 'h')
('b', 'f', 'i')
('c', 'd', 'g')
('c', 'd', 'h')
('c', 'd', 'i')
('c', 'e', 'g')
('c', 'e', 'h')
('c', 'e', 'i')
('c', 'f', 'g')
('c', 'f', 'h')
('c', 'f', 'i')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2


    [(i,v,c) for i in I for v in II for c in III]
```